# Error inserting items into sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

When I first create my database I insert some items into it but I keep getting an error when doing it and I dont know why

```
01-19 11:23:56.850: E/SQLiteDatabase(11243): Error inserting manufacturer_id=0 ball=Train name=900 Global
01-19 11:23:56.850: E/SQLiteDatabase(11243): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unrecognized token: ":": , while compiling: INSERT INTO content://com.tyczj.bowling.providers.balls/balls(manufacturer_id,ball,name) VALUES (?,?,?)
01-19 11:23:56.850: E/SQLiteDatabase(11243):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
01-19 11:23:56.850: E/SQLiteDatabase(11243):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:64)
01-19 11:23:56.850: E/SQLiteDatabase(11243):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileSql(SQLiteProgram.java:146)
01-19 11:23:56.850: E/SQLiteDatabase(11243):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileAndbindAllArgs(SQLiteProgram.java:367)
01-19 11:23:56.850: E/SQLiteDatabase(11243):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.acquireAndLock(SQLiteStatement.java:253)
01-19 11:23:56.850: E/SQLiteDatabase(11243):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:111)
01-19 11:23:56.850: E/SQLiteDatabase(11243):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1737)
01-19 11:23:56.850: E/SQLiteDatabase(11243):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1610)
01-19 11:23:56.850: E/SQLiteDatabase(11243):    at com.tyczj.bowling.providers.Manufacturers$DatabaseHelper.onCreate(Manufacturers.java:65)
01-19 11:23:56.850: E/SQLiteDatabase(11243):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:157)
01-19 11:23:56.850: E/SQLiteDatabase(11243):    at com.tyczj.bowling.providers.Manufacturers.onCreate(Manufacturers.java:226)
01-19 11:23:56.850: E/SQLiteDatabase(11243):    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:955)
01-19 11:23:56.850: E/SQLiteDatabase(11243):    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:3981)
01-19 11:23:56.850: E/SQLiteDatabase(11243):    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:3736)
01-19 11:23:56.850: E/SQLiteDatabase(11243):    at and roid.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3692)
01-19 11:23:56.850: E/SQLiteDatabase(11243):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:122)
01-19 11:23:56.850: E/SQLiteDatabase(11243):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1065)
01-19 11:23:56.850: E/SQLiteDatabase(11243):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-19 11:23:56.850: E/SQLiteDatabase(11243):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
01-19 11:23:56.850: E/SQLiteDatabase(11243):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4126)
01-19 11:23:56.850: E/SQLiteDatabase(11243):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-19 11:23:56.850: E/SQLiteDatabase(11243):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
01-19 11:23:56.850: E/SQLiteDatabase(11243):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:844)
01-19 11:23:56.850: E/SQLiteDatabase(11243):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
01-19 11:23:56.850: E/SQLiteDatabase(11243):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

in my database oncreate I get a string array (list of manufacturers) from resources and based on the manufacturer I insert items in another item into another database. it fails when inserting the items based on manufacturer

this is my manufacturers database oncreate where everything happens

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
    {
        createTables(db);
        String[] manufacturers = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.manufacturers);
        ContentValues v = new ContentValues();
        for(int i = 0; i < manufacturers.length; i++){
            Log.d("Manufacturers",manufacturers[i]);
            v.put(NAME,manufacturers[i]);
            db.insert(MANUFACTURERS_TABLE,null,v);
            String[] balls;
            if(i == 0){
                balls = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.global);
                for(int j = 0; j<balls.length;j++){
                    Log.d("Manufacturers",balls[j]);
                    v.put(Balls.MANUFACTURER_ID,i);
                    v.put(Balls.BALL,balls[j]);
                    db.insert(Balls.CONTENT_URI.toString(),null,v);
                }
            }else if(i == 1){
                balls = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.amf);
                for(int j = 0; j<balls.length;j++){
                    Log.d("Manufacturers",balls[j]);
                    v.put(Balls.MANUFACTURER_ID,i);
                    v.put(Balls.BALL,balls[j]);
                    db.insert(Balls.CONTENT_URI.toString(),null,v);
                }

            }else if(i == 2){
                balls = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.brunswick);
                for(int j = 0; j<balls.length;j++){
                    Log.d("Manufacturers",balls[j]);
                    v.put(Balls.MANUFACTURER_ID,i);
                    v.put(Balls.BALL,balls[j]);
                    db.insert(Balls.CONTENT_URI.toString(),null,v);
                }
            }else if(i == 3){
                balls = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.columbia);
                for(int j = 0; j<balls.length;j++){
                    Log.d("Manufacturers",balls[j]);
                    v.put(Balls.MANUFACTURER_ID,i);
                    v.put(Balls.BALL,balls[j]);
                    db.insert(Balls.CONTENT_URI.toString(),null,v);
                }
            }else if(i == 4){
                balls = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ebonite);
                for(int j = 0; j<balls.length;j++){
                    Log.d("Manufacturers",balls[j]);
                    v.put(Balls.MANUFACTURER_ID,i);
                    v.put(Balls.BALL,balls[j]);
                    db.insert(Balls.CONTENT_URI.toString(),null,v);
                }
            }else if(i == 5){
                balls = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.hammer);
                for(int j = 0; j<balls.length;j++){
                    Log.d("Manufacturers",balls[j]);
                    v.put(Balls.MANUFACTURER_ID,i);
                    v.put(Balls.BALL,balls[j]);
                    db.insert(Balls.CONTENT_URI.toString(),null,v);
                }
            }else if(i == 6){
                balls = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.morich);
                for(int j = 0; j<balls.length;j++){
                    Log.d("Manufacturers",balls[j]);
                    v.put(Balls.MANUFACTURER_ID,i);
                    v.put(Balls.BALL,balls[j]);
                    db.insert(Balls.CONTENT_URI.toString(),null,v);
                }
            }else if(i == 7){
                balls = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.rotogrip);
                for(int j = 0; j<balls.length;j++){
                    Log.d("Manufacturers",balls[j]);
                    v.put(Balls.MANUFACTURER_ID,i);
                    v.put(Balls.BALL,balls[j]);
                    db.insert(Balls.CONTENT_URI.toString(),null,v);
                }
            }else if(i == 8){
                balls = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.storm);
                for(int j = 0; j<balls.length;j++){
                    Log.d("Manufacturers",balls[j]);
                    v.put(Balls.MANUFACTURER_ID,i);
                    v.put(Balls.BALL,balls[j]);
                    db.insert(Balls.CONTENT_URI.toString(),null,v);
                }
            }else if(i == 9){
                balls = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.track);
                for(int j = 0; j<balls.length;j++){
                    Log.d("Manufacturers",balls[j]);
                    v.put(Balls.MANUFACTURER_ID,i);
                    v.put(Balls.BALL,balls[j]);
                    db.insert(Balls.CONTENT_URI.toString(),null,v);
                }
            }else if(i == 10){
                balls = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.motiv);
                for(int j = 0; j<balls.length;j++){
                    Log.d("Manufacturers",balls[j]);
                    v.put(Balls.MANUFACTURER_ID,i);
                    v.put(Balls.BALL,balls[j]);
                    db.insert(Balls.CONTENT_URI.toString(),null,v);
                }
            }else if(i == 11){
                balls = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.elite);
                for(int j = 0; j<balls.length;j++){
                    Log.d("Manufacturers",balls[j]);
                    v.put(Balls.MANUFACTURER_ID,i);
                    v.put(Balls.BALL,balls[j]);
                    db.insert(Balls.CONTENT_URI.toString(),null,v);
                }
            }else if(i == 12){
                balls = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.dv8);
                for(int j = 0; j<balls.length;j++){
                    Log.d("Manufacturers",balls[j]);
                    v.put(Balls.MANUFACTURER_ID,i);
                    v.put(Balls.BALL,balls[j]);
                    db.insert(Balls.CONTENT_URI.toString(),null,v);
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

this is my insert into the second database

```
@Override
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
    long rowID = db.insert(BALLS_TABLE,null, values);
    if(rowID > 0){
        Uri _uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(CONTENT_ID_URI_BASE,rowID);
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(_uri,null);
        return _uri;
    }else{
        throw new SQLException("Failed to insert row into " + uri);
    }
}
```

now I do not see anywhere in my insert where there is a `:` that it says is the problem so I dont know whats wrong. Can I not insert like this?

**EDIT:**

my other table

```
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Balls";
private static final String BALLS_TABLE = "balls";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String  AUTHORITY = "com.tyczj.bowling.providers.balls";
public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY + "/balls");
public static final Uri CONTENT_ID_URI_BASE = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY + "/balls/");
private static final UriMatcher uriMatcher;
public static final String BALL = "ball";
public static final String ID = "_id";
public static final String MANUFACTURER_ID = "manufacturer_id";

private static final HashMap<String, String> mMap;
private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;
```

and my oncreate for that table

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreate() {
    Context context = getContext();
    DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return (db == null)? false:true;
}
```

EDIT 2:

manufacturers table

```
private void createTables(SQLiteDatabase db){
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + MANUFACTURERS_TABLE + "(" + ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                NAME + " TEXT);");
    }
```

balls table

```
private void createTables(SQLiteDatabase db){
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + BALLS_TABLE + "(" + ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                 MANUFACTURER_ID + " INTEGER, " + BALL + " TEXT);");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call db.insert by directly passing the table name and not the content uri

try

```
        if(i == 0){
            balls = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.global);
            for(int j = 0; j<balls.length;j++){
                Log.d("Manufacturers",balls[j]);
                v.put(Balls.MANUFACTURER_ID,i);
                v.put(Balls.BALL,balls[j]);
                db.insert("balls",null,v);
            }
        }
```

Comment: tried that, gave me an error telling me the table does not exist

Comment: can you post the createTables(db); method

Comment: you need to create both tables together only. I think you should have only one ContentProvider class file not two.

Comment: please refer this and create both tables together in a single database helper http://code.google.com/p/androidtutorial/source/browse/trunk/%20androidtutorial/EmployeeDirectory3/src/samples/employeedirectory/DatabaseHelper.java

Answer (score 0):

Well I can see the ":" mark here:

**content://com**.tyczj.bowling.providers.balls/balls(manufacturer_id,ball,name)

Comment: well yes thats the content provider's uri

Comment: well yes, you have to encode that mark with %3A or just get the "content://" header out from your string and when you use it again, append it to your database string

Answer (score 0):

There must be some problem in defining your table. 
Check it if you have defined the columns properly.
Also if you can post that code here, will be helpful to debug.